# Using Vs studio code to perform flutter, Select chrome as web device, when i debugged, only displayed 'white screen'. There weren't error code

Tags: flutter, dart

https://github.com/gojunho4321/flutter_toonflix/commit/ee83e68fc021e83a9f6da037e7ba6ef2e6415ffe
this is code what I run in vs studio code.
I selected device as 'Chrome(web)' but when I ran the code, chrome displayed address as http://localhost:64661/#/, but there are was only 'white screen' ,no other factors(title, loading circle, etc...)
So I ran the other code, which was very simple, but the chrome web displayed white screen also.
screen was like the attached file
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in your `index.html` file in the `web` folder delete the

`<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">`

(usually it well be at line 17)

then run `flutter clean`

then run `flutter run -d chrome`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `MaterialApp` widget. A `Scaffold` in itself is not enough.

For an easy fix try this, but later you will likely want to have a separate `MaterialApp` with different pages:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});
  Future<List<dynamic>> webtoons = ApiService.getTodaysToons();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // wrap everything into a MaterialApp
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(...
```

There is also a missing `;` after the closing of `return ListView.separated(...`.